# Books like Anold's Real Algebraic Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for books on the topics covered in Arnold's Real Algebraic Geometry which doesn't have too many pre-requisites.I don't expect it to be written in the same style as Arnold's which is truly inimitable.For those not aware of this book see below:

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xchAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&dq=real+algebraic+geometry+arnold&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMImcDO_-LUxwIVwaSUCh2KRQyz#v=onepage&q=real%20algebraic%20geometry%20arnold&f=false

Mostly I am interested in complex algebraic curves,complex projective space etc but I am not prepared to read modern treatments like griffith and Harris or Huybrecht.Are there any books on these topics for people who dont know any algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham is genuinely one of the best books for visualizing algebra/complex functions that I've come across.

[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534469)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am aware of this book and I think it is excellent but I don't think it covers the topics I am interested in.